# Why is the same code in G1ANT showing different results in different iterations?

Tags: g1ant

For example, let there be statements like :-
Keyboard variable1
keyboard enter
Keyboard variable2
keyboard enter
.
.
.
.
.

In such cases, in some iterations it will be correctly entered, however in some iterations the two keyboard commands will run one after the other, then the middle enter command will run, this results in loss of characters in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by the application/system response time, try to add a 'delay' before Enter. You can also experiment with 'keydelay' in the keyboard command.

```
keyboard keydelay 50 text ♥test
```